# InvalidOperationException Nullable object must have a value

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i am using asp.net 4.0 and sql server when i am browing in the application only some times i am seeing this error and if click some thing it resolves can some one suggest me how to overcome this

'System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource
resource)

Answer (score 7):

You're likely trying to access the Value of a nullable object that is null.

From the [MSDN page on nullable types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> The Value property returns a value if one is assigned, otherwise a
>   System.InvalidOperationException is thrown.

You have various options to overcome the error. For instance:

```
int? a=null; // a test nullable object
//Console.WriteLine(a.Value); // this throws an InvalidOperationException

// using GetValueOrDefault()
Console.WriteLine(a.GetValueOrDefault()); //0 (default value for int)

//checking if a.HasValue
if(a.HasValue) Console.WriteLine(a.Value); // does not print anything as the if
                                           // is false

// using the ?? operator
Console.WriteLine(a ?? -1); // prints -1
```

Comment: why am i getting only some times

Comment: you haven't pasted the code that is causing the exception, but I can assume that sometimes your nullable object is not null (and a.Value does not throw an exception).