# How to resolve an InvalidOperationException on Bool condition?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, boolean-logic, invalidoperationexception, relaycommand

I've set up a bool property to prevent or allow a command to fire based on that bool being set to true.

In the current implementation, I check within the bool that certain values are not null before setting the bool to true.

**Question:**

Why do I get an InvalidOperationException on the condition within the bool?

**Overview of code:**

Bool property `CanSendCommand`, which is used as a param in the Relay command below:

```
private bool CanSendCommand()
{
    if (SelectedParkDuration.Value != null && RegNumber != string.Empty && SelectedZone.ZoneName != null)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

`TagRequestCommand` which is called initially in a load method on class initilization. The command itself is bound to a button press on the UI.

For context RegNumber is type string, SelectedParkingDuration is ?TimeSpan, and SelectedZone.ZoneName is a string within a property:

```
    private void LoadCommands()
    {
        TagRequestCommand = new RelayCommand(async () =>
        {
            await SendParkingTagSMSRequest();
        } ,CanSendCommand );
    }
```

I've copied the exception details, which tells me the values for the condition are null which should be okay as its handled in the bool condition. I see then that there is line pointing to a "Nullable object must have a value", which tells me maybe my Timespan property SelectedParkDuration should have a value. But I'm not sure how it can have a value before a value has been selected.

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=Nullable object must have a value.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource resource)
       at System.Nullable`1.get_Value()
       at Parking_Tag_Picker_WRT.ViewModel.TagRequestViewModel.CanSendCommand()
  InnerException:
```

Screenshot of the autos windows during runtime:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple code in Linqpad to reproduce the scenario  you have suggested:

```
void Main()
{
    // Test.SelectedParkDuration = 5;

    var result = Test.SelectedParkDuration.Value; // Invalid operation exception with above line commented out

    result.Dump();
}

public class Test
{
    public static int? SelectedParkDuration { get; set;}
}
```

if you want `Test.SelectedParkDuration.Value;` to be successful, then first assign, else it will be `Null Reference exception`, .Net prefers `Invalid Operation Exception` to suggest that usage is incorrect, else if you expect value to be Null then should not use the `Value property`.

To make above code work comment out the line:

```
// Test.SelectedParkDuration = 5;
```

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902244/invalidoperationexception-nullable-object-must-have-a-value) too

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `SelectedParkDuration.Value != null` is the part which throws the exception. You can simply check `SelectedParkDuration != null`

More information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6(v=vs.110).aspx